# getting "Whitelabel Error Page" running actuator health and mappings urls

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am starting with spring boot, running a demo spring web starter project, I was checking the spring actuator functionality by calling http://localhost:8080/mappings and http://localhost:8080/health  ... It's giving me the "Whitelabel Error Page" ... the log is not showing anything

[image]

the project is a very simple boot application created in STS with one `@RestController` which is working fine

**Main class :**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static HashMap<Long,Student> hmStudent;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //dummt code
          SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Rest Controller :**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.DemoApplication;
import com.example.demo.entities.Student;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/student")
class StudentService{

   @RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public HashMap<Long,Student> getAllStudents(){
      return DemoApplication.hmStudent;
   }
.
.
.
.
}
```

**application properties :**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:ibmwas
spring.datasource.username=u
spring.datasource.password=p
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What is the problem and how can I the logs be more descriptive

Comment: Have you tried with http://localhost:8080/actuator/mappings

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE the default prefix for all endpoints is `/actuator`
So if you want to check the health of an application, you should go to `/actuator/health`

To make an actuator endpoint available via HTTP, it needs to be both enabled and exposed.

By default:

- only the `/health` and `/info` endpoints are exposed.
- all endpoints but `/shutdown` are enabled (only /health and /info are exposed)

To expose all endpoints you have to add the following line into `application.properties`:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, actually I tried it (http://localhost:8080/actuator/health) it's giving the same result, I tried adding `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` it's giving a warning : `unknown property`

Comment: @osamayaccoub , set the following property along with the above-  management.security.enabled=false

Comment: thanks @AviC ... it did it .... but as I see from the property, this disables security ... right ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  After some trial and error, i got the actuator output when i hit http://localhost:8080 on the browser, it took me to the HAL browser . From the HAL's explorer, i typed actuator, which took me to http://localhost:8080/browser/index.html#http://localhost:8080/actuator and this is where are all the details I was looking for at http://localhost:8080/application was present.

Note Spring boot version that I am using is : 2.0.6 SNAPSHOT.

And, in the application.properties, i had added management.security.enabled=false. w/o this i could see very minimal info.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.